# abstract algebra , group theory , centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

if G is a group with a group element a such that a^5=e , show that c(a)=c(a^3) ?

to show that c(a) ⊆ c(a^3) ,
 let g ∈ c(a) then ag=ga . (a^3)g=(a^2)ag=aa(ga)=a(ga)a=(ga)aa=g(a^3) , so , g ∈ c(a^3) .

But for the other inclusion , I'm lost . can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\in C_G(a)\implies xa=ax\implies xa^3=axa^2=a^2xa=a^3x\implies x\in C_G(a^3)$$

The other direction:

$$x\in C_G(a^3)\implies xa^3=a^3x\implies xa=xa^6=x(a^3)a^3=a^3xa^3=...$$

Finish the idea.

Answer (score 0):

since $gcd(3,5)=1 \implies$ $<a>=<a^3>$ which means if $a^3\in H$ then $a\in H$ for any subgroup $H$ and vice versa which force $C_G(a)=C_G(a^3)$.